# How to support multiple configurations in persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, deployment

I am developing a pure Java app with Hibernate in JPA mode. The file persistence.xml contains a single persistence unit which:

- contains access credentials to the database
- lists all used entites using class tags
- defines other options such as auto-creation of the schema on every start of the application

Now we are releasing the application and I want to have a configuration for: testing mode, development mode and production mode. They would obviously have different database access credentials and auto-update option.

The only possibilities I can think of have only drawbacks to me:

1. Have multiple persistence.xml? Bad idea because the entity classes are declared inside the persistence unit. I would have to maintain them in three persistence.xml files
2. Have multiple persistence units in one persistence.xml? Also bad idea because I'd have to copy all entity class tags to each of them.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of is if you have a way of detecting the environment of your application, you could launch it with different properties.
Instead of calling:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("our.unit");
```

use

```
Map<String, Object> props = new TreeMap<>();
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("our.unit",props);
```

where the properties will be filled depending on the environment.

That is of course, unless you're using CDI.

Comment: Sounds great. I wasn't aware you can pass a second parameter. I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @Wombat any luck?

Comment: Your solution is working and I am using it as the current solution. However it has some weak points: Passing in "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" does not work (because it's not a JPA standard parameter). If we keep that parameter in "the single" persistence.xml we are risking that one may forget to turn it off and the production database will be wiped away. Therefore I would prefer having multiple persistence.xml but that does not work because I have to list all entites there, otherwise they will not be found by EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: I traced through their 5.2 code and see no reason for the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to not be taken into account like that. In fact a lot of hibernate-specific properties take only non-string objects and are passed that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to copy all of  tags to each of them if you will use same entities with both persistence units ?

why you just didn't use

> `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

for example :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit_1">
        <provider> xxx </provider>
        <jta-data-source> xxxx  </jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties> 
            //Properties of first persistence unit
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit_2">
        <provider> xxx </provider>
        <jta-data-source> xxxx  </jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties> 
            //Properties of second persistence unit
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

and in this case you need to use it by name, for example

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceUnit_1")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: If I don't list all classes in persistence.xml Hibernate will tell me that the entities are not mapped. All entities are located in a different project of which the sources are included. Unfortunately your solution does not work for me.

Comment: `exclude-unlisted-classes` only works so far as the entities are in the in the same classpath level as the `persistence.xml`. Another solution is if you can separate them in their own `jar` and add `<jar-file>myentities.jar</jar-file>` to your `persistence.xml`. That forces Hibernate to look for the file in the full scope of the application, as does listing the classes individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On your src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="schemaTest" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>    
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/SCHEMA_TEST?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


    <persistence-unit name="schemaProd" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x:x/SCHEMA_PROD?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

Now, on the method that makes the query:

String 'argSchema' should be set between 'schemaTest' and 'schemaProd' depending on your current need.

```
String argSchema = "schemaTest";
SessionFactory factory = (SessionFactory) 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(argSchema);
        
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
            
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
...
tx.commit();
```